# Match error in nuxt3 app with locomotive scroll

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, locomotive-scroll

I have nuxt3 project with locomotive scroll and gsap (repo: https://github.com/cyprianwaclaw/Skandynawia-Przystan). I have a problem, when I change page ep. index to test and reverse page dons't change and I my console has error: locomotive-scroll.esm.js:1897 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match').

How to fix it ?

Answer (score -4):

The error message you're seeing suggests that there's an issue with the
match
method being called on an undefined value. This could be caused by a few different things, but one possibility is that the
match
method is being called on an element that doesn't exist in the DOM.

To fix this issue, you can try adding some error handling to your code to check if the element exists before calling the
match
method. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to handle this error:

```
// Get the element to check
const element = document.querySelector('.my-element');

// Check if the element exists
if (element) {
  // Call the match method on the element
  const match = element.match(/some-regex-pattern/);
  // Do something with the match result
} else {
  // Handle the error
  console.error('Element not found');
}
```

This code will first check if the element exists using the
if (element)
statement. If the element exists, it will call the
match
method on the element as before. If the element doesn't exist, it will log an error message to the console using
console.error('Element not found')
.

You can modify this code to handle other types of errors that might occur in your code as well. For example, you might want to handle errors related to the
querySelector
method by checking if the return value is null or undefined, or by using a try-catch block to catch any errors that might occur

Comment: ChatGPT? Is that you?

Comment: what's the meaning of ChatGPT

Comment: Answering like this only 2 minutes after the question is asked is brilliant

Comment: No. i'm sorry if i was not clear by Answering like this only 2 minutes after the question is asked but i had this text in my notepad. i answered like this question last two weeks

Comment: but what's the meaning of ChatGPT

Comment: Suspected of being AI answer